# Displaying an image in a bootstrap modal with form populated dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I have been looking at tutorials and posted questions trying to workout how this can be done, without any luck.

I am working on a script that loads a Bootstrap modal which contains a form auto populated from the result of a JSON result. The form is to allow the user to edit the displayed record and save it. I have the process working with one last thing to complete. The loaded record contains an name of an image and I need to display that image in the form.

The code which calls the data:

```
success:function(data) {
    var result = JSON.stringify(data);
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log("DATA", result );
    $('#Editrecordid').val(result[0]);
    $('#Editpromotionname').val(result[1]);
    $('#Editboard').val(result[2]);
    //$('#board option[value=(.+ result[2] +.]').prop('selected', true);
    $('#Editscreenlocation').val(result[3]);
    if(result[4] == 'L') {
       $('#Editorientation').val('Landscape');
    } else {
       $('#Editorientation').val('Portrait');
    }
    
    // THE VAR BELOW CONTAINS THE PATH TO THE IMAGE FILE ON THE SERVER
    var imagepath = '../../../../signage/promotion_images/'+ result[15] +'/'+ result[2] +'/'+ result[5];
    console.log("Image path", imagepath);
    // I END UP THE THE BELOW DIV ID POPULATED WITH THE PATH AND IMAGE NAME
    $('#Editpromotionimage').val(imagepath);
    
    $('#Editmediatype').val(result[6]);
    $('#fromdate').val(result[7]);
    $('#fromtimeh').val(result[8]);
    $('#fromtimem').val(result[9]);
    $('#todate').val(result[10]);
    $('#totimeh').val(result[11]);
    $('#totimem').val(result[12]);
    $('#displaywidth').val(result[13]);
    editw = result[13];
    console.log("editw",editw);
    $('#displayheight').val(result[14]);
    edith = result[14];
    console.log("edith",edith);

    $('#insert').val("Update");
    $('#Editlandscape0').hide();
$('#edit_data_Modal_2').modal("show");
}
```

If I temporary have a textbox in the form:

```
<input type="text" class="timetext" name="EditImagePath" id="Editpromotionimage" value="">
```

the correct path and filename appear.

My question is how can I display the actual image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an img tag and attach it that way, so just add the img tag to where you want it to display in the modal.

```
<img id="Editpromotionimage" class="img-responsive">
```

then using jQuery:

```
$("#Editpromotionimage").attr("src",imagepath);
```

Comment: many thanks. for whatever reason I did not try that, perfect.

Comment: no problem. I fixed a typo too, attr was missing a t.